# GIT used in the TFS/VS environment

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs

From what I understand, GIT can be used with TFS2013/VS2013 in the following configurations:

1. GIT can be used as the repository of TFS.  TFS is then used, of course, from Visual Studio. (VS -> TFS -> GIT)
2. GIT can be used directly from Visual Studio. (VS -> GIT)

I need to know if these two configurations are accurate and if so, why choose one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your point with the *method 1*. Seems you mean **you want to use git exclusively on your local machine but push to TFS on the server** then using a `git-TF`/ `git-TFS` tool, which is a two-way bridge between TFS (Team Foundation Server) and git, similar to git-svn. It fetches TFS commits into a git repository, and lets you push your updates back to TFS.

**For example:**  You can clone your "DEV" branch from TFS to a local git repo, work exclusively in git and use feature branches. When your code is ready to send back to Dev then you can rebase and push it. Detail commands please refer this link: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs

---

For *method 2*, **it's a recommend way** on TFS2013/VS2013. *Brian Harry* goes through some great detail about the [new integration of Git repositories](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/19/enterprise-grade-git.aspx) into the [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com) as well as [Team Foundation Server 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-preview).  There are quite a few interesting points he makes that are particularly important to enterprise and generally for teams who care about having a solid hosting of their Git repos:

> **Ease of installation** – We’ve now made installing Git a seamless part
> of installing TFS. There’s nothing to go and track down and download.
> Nothing to install and configure separately. You just install TFS 2013
> and automatically get Git support.
>
> **Support and servicing** – Because we are shipping it, we support it.
> This means if you have any problem, you can contact our support and
> get help. You will receive security updates, hot fixes, regular
> Updates and more all the same way you are used to getting them. We’ll
> work hard to make sure your TFS Server is healthy and up to date
> regardless of which features you are using.
>
> **High availability** – Since early on, we’ve worked to make TFS support
> high availability.  Our Git support is no exception – we support all
> the same things you are used to with TFS – load balancing and
> clustering to ensure that your server will continue to run in spite of
> hardware and software failures, Geo-replication if you need to be
> certain that you maintain business continuity even in the face of
> regional outages, online backup and restore as an integrated part of
> TFS so that your existing enterprise grade backup and restore policies
> (full, incremental and transaction log) will continue to work (giving
> you good RTO and RPO).
>
> **Scale** – Like with TFS, you can scale your TFS installation seamlessly
> as your needs grow. This includes scaling out both the application
> tier and the storage tier as you need to add additional capacity.
>
> **Ease of management** – Our Git implementation is fully integrated in to
> TFS so that all of your management policies can continue unchanged –
> service account management, hardware migration, software patching,
> backup & restore, monitoring, permission management and more.
>
> **Integrated Authentication** – Our Git support fully integrates Windows
> Active Directory authentication so that all of your access control,
> auditing, etc can be done against a consistent and manageable
> infrastructure. As part of this, all changes are audited against an
> authorized identity assuring you know who made each change.
>
> **Enhanced permissions** – We’ve built (and are building) a bunch of
> additional repository and permission management capabilities that
> allow administrators to “control the chaos”. The first set include the
> ability to manage repositories (create, delete, rename, etc) and
> repository level permissions that control Read, Write and Administer
> permissions. We also include a 4th permission that addresses a key
> issue many customers have had with Git – “Force push”, which
> effectively enables users to “alter history”.  While we enable this
> ability, we also enable administrators to disable it with a
> permission.  We are also working on additional permissions now – like
> branch level permissions that will enable administrators to control
> who can create, delete and use individual branches.  In this way,
> developers can use branching any way they choose locally but, when
> they are going to push back to the master repo, they are constrained
> by policies the administrator configures.
>
> **ALM integration** – And, of course, we are fully integrating Git into
> the TFS ALM workflows – work item tracking, build automation,
> reporting, code review, and more. Not all of that integration is
> complete yet but we’ll be fleshing it out through the 2013 Updates
> and, when we are done, we should have full parity on ALM integration
> capabilities between Team Foundation Version Control and Git Version
> Control.
>
> **Localization** – Like the rest of our product, our Git capabilities will
> be localized into the same languages as the rest of VS making it more
> approachable by parts of the non-English speaking world.

Source:  [Enterprise Grade Git Repos](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/19/enterprise-grade-git.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The process for the first approach should be: VS->Git->TFS rather than VS->TFS->Git.